# Using HiLo ef Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, hilo

```
class Example
{
    public OwnId Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}

class AnotherExample
{
    public OwnId Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}

class OwnId
{
    public long Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have this code, I want to generate an id using HiLo but I get an error:

```
builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
builder.Property(e => e.Id).UseHiLo();
```

> System.ArgumentException: PostgreSQL sequences cannot be used to generate values for the property 'Id' on ent
> ity type 'Example' because the property type is 'OwnId'. Sequences can only be used with integer propert
> ies.

Is it possible to use my structure?

Comment: Since the error message specifically spells out that it can only be used with integer properties, I'm guessing no. EF has the concept of [value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations) which may still work but I don't think so.

Comment: thanks, value converters still working